# Converting ng-repeat table to card

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-material

i was woundering how i can convert this type of complex ng-repeat from using table to repeat  in AngularJS material design.

My markup looks like this now:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>AccountName</th>
                        <th>AccountID</th>
                        <th>ContainerID</th>
                        <th>ContainerName</th>
                        <th>Path</th>
                        <th>Favorite</th>
                        <th>Hide</th>
                        <th>Count</th>

                    </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody ng-repeat="(k,v) in containers">
                    <tr ng-repeat="(k1,v1) in v" ng-if="v1.accountId!= null || v1.accountId == ''">
                        <td><a href="{{v1.tagManagerUrl}}">{{ k }}</a></td>
                        <td>{{ v1.accountId }}</td>
                        <td>{{ v1.containerId }}</td>
                        <td>{{ v1.name }}</td>
                        <td><a href="/gui/tags/{{v1.path}}">View Container</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Ive tried using this markup for md-cards but it gets all wrong:

```
<md-card ng-repeat="(k,v) in containers">
    <md-card-content ng-repeat="(k1,v1) in v">
        <h2 class="md-title">{{ v1.name }}</h2>
        <p>
            {{ v1.accountId }}
        </p>
    </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

If you can see the images the request and the ng-repeat it dont look like a table where you have each row for each account/container:
[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you want exactly ? Just a divider between every element of your different accounts?

Comment: Don't repeat the account name and use css to divide them

Comment: @Zooly, yes i want to divide between every element. But "Account1" has 2 "containers" and those are not divided, i want to divide by container but also display accountname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with this code:

```
<div class='md-padding' layout="row" flex>
    <div layout="row" flex>
        <div class="parent" layout="column" ng-repeat="(k,v) in containers">
            <md-card ng-repeat="(k1,v1) in v" ng-if="v1.accountId!= null || v1.accountId == ''">
                <md-card-content>
                    AccountName: {{k}}<br>
                    Accountid: {{ v1.accountId }} <br>
                    ContainerName: {{ v1.name }}
                </md-card-content>
                <div class="md-actions" layout="row" layout-align="end center">
                    <md-button>Save</md-button>
                    <md-button>View</md-button>
                </div>
            </md-card>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to repeat the `Acccount` value, you can do something like this:

```
<md-card ng-repeat="(k,v) in containers">
    <md-card-content ng-repeat="(k1,v1) in v">
        <h2 class="md-title" ng-if="$first">{{ v1.name }}</h2>
        <p>
            {{ v1.accountId }}
        </p>
    </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

Comment: i want to have Accountname also. The problem is that "Account1" has 2 "Containers" and "Account2" has 1 "Container". Should it not be able to divide by containers and now Account? or divide this with css like @charliefl said in comments but i dont know how. Your code still does not divide the containers

Comment: I don't understand your point. But for sure you should write generic code instead of adapt it for a specific case

Comment: im using simple ng-repeat to display some data in Cards. If you look at my JSON structure and the Cards you see that they match. BUT i want to divide on "container"-level not "account" because "account" has multiple containers that should be divided in each own cards. Just like a table creates a new row for each entry

Comment: So just place a  `<md-divider></md-divider>` where you need. I'd say at the end of second repeater